# Let $f$ be analytic in $D(0,2)$. Assume that for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$ $\int_{ |z|=1} {f(z)\over(n+1)z−1}dz=0$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z∈D(0,2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be analytic in $D(0,2)$. Assume that for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$
$\int_{
|z|=1}
{f(z)\over(n+1)z−1}dz=0$.
Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z∈D(0,2)$.

I'm thinking about a contradiction proof. Assuming that $f(z)$ doesn't not equal zero and contradicting the assumption. I'm not sure though. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Look what is it $f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ by Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not sure I understand the hint though.

Comment: @DerpMagoo Do you know what is it Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: Yes, this, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: @DerpMagoo Yes. And if you take $a=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and look at your condition, you will get... Try it.

Comment: Since $f$ is analytic I can choose $a={1\over (n+1)}$ and substitute $a$ into the cauchy integral formula which gives me $0$ from the condition and thus $f=0$?

Comment: @DerpMagoo You should get $f(\frac{1}{n+1})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, note that $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0 \in D(0,2)$ when $n \to \infty$ (so, you have sequence tending to element of $D(0,2)$ and on that sequence your function is zero, so...)

Comment: Yes, wow that is really clever. So the result follows.